# Replace value in column with dplyr based on given index

Tags: r, replace, dplyr

I am trying to replace a value (e.g. always `1`) in a specific column of a dataframe. The column index for the replacement is given in column `j` .

It works with a for loop:

```
data <- data.frame(v1 = rep(0, 10),
               v2 = rep(0, 10),
               j = sample(1:2, 10, replace = TRUE))

for (i in 1: nrow(data)){
  data[i, (data$j[i])] <- 1
}
```

I am looking for the `dplyr` way of handling this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily done with `row/column` indexing and it should be faster

```
data[cbind(1:nrow(data), data$j)] <- 1
data
#   v1 v2 j
#1   0  1 2
#2   1  0 1
#3   0  1 2
#4   0  1 2
#5   0  1 2
#6   0  1 2
#7   0  1 2
#8   1  0 1
#9   1  0 1
#10  0  1 2
```

---

Or another way is

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
tibble::rownames_to_column(data, var = "rn") %>%
           gather(Var, Val, v1:v2) %>% 
           mutate(Val= +(sub("\\D+", "", Var)==j)) %>% 
           spread(Var, Val) %>% 
           arrange(as.numeric(rn)) %>%
           select_(.dots=names(data))
#   v1 v2 j
#1   0  1 2
#2   1  0 1
#3   0  1 2
#4   0  1 2
#5   0  1 2
#6   0  1 2
#7   0  1 2
#8   1  0 1
#9   1  0 1
#10  0  1 2
```

Comment: I didn't downvote. But actually I am looking for the dplyr way of handling this situation. Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @Fritzbrause  I posted a solution from the tidyverse/dplyr family

Comment: Great! Thank you. Base version is indeed much easier. I prefer this solution as it is easier to adopt to several variables.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a dplyr version, using `bind_rows`. First let's set up data:

```
set.seed(2)
data <- data.frame(v1 = rep(0, 10),
                   v2 = rep(0, 10),
                   j = sample(1:2, 10, replace = TRUE))
```

Then we load dplyr and use `do` to act on each row. Here we use `do` to return one data frame per row, and `bind_rows` to merge them all together. The data in each row can be accessed using the `.` variable.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
    do(data.frame(v1 = ifelse(.$j == 1, 1, .$v1),
                  v2 = ifelse(.$j == 2, 1, .$v2),
                  j = .$j)) %>% 
    bind_rows() 


#   v1 v2 j
#1   1  0 1
#2   0  1 2
#3   0  1 2
#4   1  0 1
#5   0  1 2
#6   0  1 2
#7   1  0 1
#8   0  1 2
#9   1  0 1
#10  0  1 2
```

An even shorter solution, suggested by @Akrun, is:

```
data %>% mutate(v1 = +(j==1), v2 = +(j==2))
```

Comment: You can also do `data %>% mutate(v1 = +(j==1), v2 = +(j==2))`.  Assuming there are only two columns

Comment: Oh very nice, @akrun! You should add that as an answer.

Comment: It is similar to your thought process.  Please add it to your answer

Comment: Fair enough, will!